# React runtime errors - What happens if an expected prop is not given? ErrorBoundary and PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component `Profile` which might receive this a prop:

```js
RootProfile.propTypes = {
  route: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      userData: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.shape({
          id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        }),
        PropTypes.shape({
          username: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        }),
      ]),
    }),
  }).isRequired,
};
```

In the code of `Profile`, I do:

```js
function RootProfile({route: { params }}){ 
   const currentUser = useCurrentUser();

   let { userData = currentUser.data } = params ?? {};

   // Consume the most up-to-date data from context
   userData = useUpdatedUserData(userData);

   if (userData.id) {
      return <Profile userData={userData} />
   }

   // We will need to fetch the user by username!
   return <ProfileFetcher username={userData.username} />
}
```

As you can see, if `userData.id` is not defined, I do not render the my lazy loading `Profile` component... Instead, I render my `ProfileFetcher` component, which just fetches the user data by username and stores it to my context (which I consume in `RootProfile` to re-render the screen when everything is ready).

My question is: what if, for an unexpected reason, `Profile` doesn't receive the "required" prop fields for its work? I mean, what if it doesn't receive neither userData.id nor userData.username?

Should I do something like

```js
function RootProfile({route: { params }}){ 
   const currentUser = useCurrentUser();

   let { userData = currentUser.data } = params ?? {};

   // Consume the most up-to-date data from context
   userData = useUpdatedUserData(userData);

   if (userData.id) {
      return <Profile userData={userData} />
   } else if (userData.username) {
      // We will need to fetch the user by username!
      return <ProfileFetcher username={userData.username} />
   } else {
     throw new Error("id or username is required");
   }
}
```

`??` I mean, is it considered "correct" to throw an error inside a React component?

Or, should all these situations be handled with `ErrorBoundaries` and `PropTypes`?

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the prop may be undefined consider removing `isRequired` and making it optional. However, in answer to your question `PropTypes` library doesn't throw errors in production mode so you can't catch it with an `ErrorBoundary` you have to check it menually.